# How to capture non-browser data using Fiddler

Tags: web-services, wcf, fiddler

I have a web application which communicates with a "wcf web service app"  which is hosted on the same machine, "wcf web service app" works like a proxy, it communicates with another web service which is hosted on another machine and retrieves some of the data from that server.

When I monitor requests on my server using fiddler I can only monitor the traffic between the browser and the web service app on my server. I can not monitor the traffic between my "web service app" and "remote web service app", is it possible to monitor the second traffic I mentioned above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fiddler is a proxy; it captures any traffic you send to it. You need to configure your web service to send its traffic through Fiddler. You will probably find http://www.telerik.com/blogs/capturing-traffic-from-net-services-with-fiddler helpful.